# Decorator isn't getting arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle, python-decorators

I'm trying to add an `access_rights` decorator to my Bottle app to check permissions when accessing a route. However, it's not getting the decorated function's arguments, which causes an error when trying to call my decorated function again.

Here's an example of code using the decorator:

```
@route('/users')
@access_rights({'POST': ['admin']})
def users(user):
    pass
```

The `user` parameter comes from a Bottle plugin I wrote that gets the user from the token passed with the request. This is my current decorator:

```
def access_rights(permissions):
    def decorator(f):    
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Check permissions rights here (not implemented yet)

            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

With this, I get `TypeError: users() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` when doing a `GET /users`, meaning `args` and `kwargs` were both empty. However, when I change the decorator as follows, it works:

```
def access_rights(permissions):
    def decorator(f):  
        return f

    return decorator
```

I haven't worked with decorators a lot, but from my understanding, both implementations above should call the `users` function with its original parameters, yet for some reason the first one doesn't get the parameters. Why is that?

Comment: This code works for me. If your second decorator syntax works, then that implies you are not using it with arguments: ie you're doing just `@access_rights` rather than `@access_rights(whatever)`.

Comment: Maybe somewhere the functions name is checked? In that case, a `@functools.wraps(f)` above the wrapper should help.

Comment: Are you using py2 or py3? I don't think it makes a huge difference, but I'm curious.

Comment: Tried using `functools.wraps` already unfortunately, it didn't help. I did forget to specify something in my question (editing after this comment): the `user` parameter comes from a Bottle plugin; could this influence things?

Comment: Using Python 2.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm definitely passing arguments, but does that really influence things here? I'm not using `permissions` for now. From my understanding, the arguments passed to `wrapper` are supposed to be the ones originally passed to `users`, right?

Comment: Well, it's not the arguments, but the function call within the decorator that's important. If you use your decorator as `@access_rights()` - whether or not you put anything inside those parentheses - then you need the second level of nesting; if you don't, you just need one level. The fact that you're getting that error indicates that you're not doing that.

Comment: I really wish I made such a "dumb" mistake, but the example code above matches exactly what I have in my code, yet it still triggers the error. Also checked my Bottle version just in case; I'm on the latest one (0.12.13).

Answer (score 0):

Your route handler, function `users`, expects one parameter.

But your decorator, `access_rights`, which you wrap around `users`, isn't passing a `user` param; it's just passing any params that it received (and, in this case, there aren't any, hence the "0 given" part of the error message).

An example should help clarify. Here's a small but complete working app, based on your original code:

```
from bottle import route, Bottle

app = Bottle()

def access_rights(permissions):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Check permissions rights here (not implemented yet)

            the_user = 'ron'  # hard-coded for this example

            return f(the_user, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@app.route('/users')
@access_rights({'POST': ['admin']})
def users(user):
    return ['hello, {}'.format(user)]


app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Note that the only substantial change I made was to have `access_rights` actually pass a user param on down the line.  (How it determines the user is, naturally, up to you--presumably it's the "not implemented yet" part that you called out in your comment).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I definitely understand that the `user` parameter isn't getting passed, but that isn't my decorator's job. As stated in my question, that `user` parameter is generated and passed by a plugin, so it shouldn't be handled by the decorator. What doesn't make sense to me is that returning `f` directly, instead of the `wrapper` that just calls `f` with the arguments it was passed, doesn't yield the same result. What am I missing here?